# Java: search file for string occurences in every line

Tags: java, string, search

I'd like to search my entire text file using the first String in every line. I want to take that first String and find how many times it occurs in the file, then write that number in front of the line.

How do I search the file for that first String in EVERY line? How do I say that I want to find its second/third occurrence? And, lastly, how do I do this for every single line in the file?

Here is how it would work:

If the first String is the first occurrence, write a 1 before that line.

For the second occurrence of that particular String, write a 2 before that line.

For the third occurrence of that String, write a 3 before that line.

This is what I have in mind (though I am completely open to a new idea):

```
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( "myfile" ));

   String line;
   String firstString;

        while ((line= br.readLine() ) != null)
          { String arr[] = line.split( " ");
            firstString = arr[0];

          //if firstString only occurs once
          bw.write ("1" + line);

          //if firstString occurs twice
          bw.write ("2" + line);

          //if firstString occurs three times
          bw.write ("3" + line);
```

Small Sample Input:

```
 Cater Megan 12354134 employee23411
 White Regan 54321123 employee90843
 White Haley 09834809 employee09842
 Rohn Smith 98234789 employee23848
 White Devon 0983489 employee75401
 Cater John 09883548 employee09834
```

Sample Output:

```
 1Cater Megan 12354134 employee23411
 1White Regan 54321123 employee90843
 2White Haley 09834809 employee09842
 1Rohn Smith 98234789 employee23848
 3White Devon 0983489 employee75401
 2Cater John 09883548 employee09834
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: How do I search the file for that first String in every line? How do I say that I want to find its second/third occurrence? And, lastly, how do I do this for every line?

Comment: Try to do it with a pen and paper yourself to develop a method for this. Put a ruler under the line you currently read, and hide all the other lines. It's the only line you can see. What do you do to keep tabs and write the lines properly?

Comment: RealSkeptic's comment is a very good suggestion; whenever you're stuck on an "algorithmic" problem, try manually doing it yourself on paper or a whiteboard first, then transfer what you figured out to code. As it stands, your question is a bit too broad, as any answer would be essentially doing your work for you. Feel free to edit or post a new question when you've encountered a specific problem or question (that has not already been asked here before).

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Set;

public class stringval {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String string=new String("Hi");     
    String input=null;
    HashMap<String, Integer> countlines=new LinkedHashMap();//<String, Integer>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> checkfirstname=new HashMap<>();
    BufferedReader br=null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/test.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        while ((input= br.readLine() ) != null){
            String[] firstname=input.split(" ");
            if(checkfirstname.containsKey(firstname[0])==true){
                Integer i=checkfirstname.get(firstname[0]);
                countlines.put(input, i+1);             
                checkfirstname.put(firstname[0], i+1);
            }
            else{
                countlines.put(input,1);
                checkfirstname.put(firstname[0],1);
            }


        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Set<String> keys=countlines.keySet();
    for(String s:keys)
        System.out.println(countlines.get(s)+s);
}

}

Output:
1Cater Megan 12354134 employee23411
1White Regan 54321123 employee90842
2White Haley 09834809 employee90842
1Rohn Smith 98234789 employee23848
3White Devon 0983489 employee75401
2Cater John 09883548 employee09834
```

Comment: Did this program run for you? It looks great but I cannot get it to run

Comment: Copied the complete program with output i got in my environment . Hope this helps you.

Comment: That `countlines` thing? Not necessary.

Comment: countlines is the one where real output are stored and display at the end. The other hashmap is used to check the first name and its occurences so far.

Comment: I know. But it's still not necessary. You don't actually have to *store* the lines nor wait for the end to display them.

Comment: Instead of adding that hashmap Printing like System.out.println((i+1)+input); will be sufficient you mean

Comment: Indeed, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Read all the lines at once, then you can just iterate through them and make necessary checks to know how many times the first string of one line appears as the first string of another line to keep count.

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

public class yourClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<String> sampleInput = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(yourSampleInput));
        for (int i = 0; i < sampleInput.size(); i++) {
            String input = sampleInput.get(i);

            // This line has already been tagged with a count, so just skip it
            if (Character.isDigit(input.charAt(0))) {
                continue;
            }

            // You already know this is the first occurrence
            int count = 1;
            sampleInput.set(i, count + " " + input);
            String[] inputPieces = input.split(" ");

            // Check remaining lines after the line you are on to see if there is a match
            for (int j = i + 1; j < sampleInput.size(); j++) {
                if (sampleInput.get(j).startsWith(inputPieces[0])) {
                    // This is another occurence of the line that you are processing from the outer for loop
                    count++;
                    sampleInput.set(j, count + " " + input);
                }
            }
        }

        for (String output : sampleInput) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: There is a way of doing it in a single loop, without filling up memory with the actual lines.

Comment: @RealSkeptic After doing this, I realize that a HashMap would work too, where the key is the First string and the value is the number of occurrences.  However, given the OP is probably just learning, I figure a basic approach is good to start with before exploring the goodies of the Java libraries.